# Most ideal Black-body!

Tags: thermodynamics

According to the definition of Black-body, it absorbs all of the wavelength irradiates on it. A recent material [absorbs 96.4%](http://www.physics4all.com/its-not-black-its-super-black/)  visible light rays. Therefore , can we say that it is the most closest (ideal) blackbody?

Comment: My biased opinion: stars are better blackbodies.

Comment: @KyleKanos Normal stars emit excess energy from fusion, not just from thermal equilibrium.  Maybe you mean a white dwarf?

Answer (score 1):

This material absorbs visible light, but ideal black body absorbs the whole spectrum regardless of frequency (including gamma rays). There are better approximations of black body than this material, like the stars. Black holes are probably the closest black body in the universe.

In laboratories we are using [things like this](http://www.omega.com/manuals/manualpdf/M3638.pdf) to approximate black bodies.

Answer (score 1):

A question like this appeared recently: [Is it possible to have a perfectly black material?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121536/is-it-possible-to-have-a-perfectly-black-material/121538#121538)

Which I ANSWERED:

> We can make it absorb a lot of energy but if you read about black-body
>   radiation effect you will notice that as energy is introduced into the
>   object it will similarly radiate a small amount of the energy back, at
>   room temperature appears black, as most of the energy it radiates is
>   infra-red and cannot be perceived by the human eye. At higher
>   temperatures, black bodies glow with increasing intensity and colors
>   that range from dull red to blindingly brilliant blue-white as the
>   temperature increases.
>
> This means that later even if we did have an $100$ percent absorbing
>   materials of all electro-magnetic radiation the object will radiate
>   some energy due to heating or other similar process. That in mind, it
>   will always leak out some energy.To conclude, we could say it will
>   only absorb radiation for short-time before releasing enough photons
>   which could be detected by an photon detector, therefore "breaking"
>   the truly blackest or absorbing material due to this effect.
>
> As a summary as long as the object absorbs some form of energy it can
>   never be completely black.
>
> To learn more pertaining black-body radiation, read this:
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation
>
> Furthermore, an blackhole is very black however it even is not as the
>   power in the Hawking radiation (if it was proven, currently it is
>   hypothesized) from a solar mass $M$ which is equal to $1.98855\pm
> > 0.00025 * 10^{30}$ black hole turns out to be a minuscule 9 × 10−29 watts. It is indeed an extremely good approximation to call such an
>   object 'black'. As  $$ P =\hbar c^2/15360\pi G^2M^2 = 9.004 * 10^{-29}
> > $$
>
> That being said, even black-holes one of the strongest objects cannot
>   escape being truly  black.

Check This: 
[Is it possible to have a perfectly black material?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121536/is-it-possible-to-have-a-perfectly-black-material/121538#121538)

Comment: Dear Rohan Vijjhalwar, it is usually frown upon to directly copy-paste [identical answers](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/121538/2451). (The problem is if everybody start to copy-paste identical answers en mass.)