# Is there any material that does not return/reflect light?

Tags: material-science

I am looking for a material that is total dark, something that even when you illuminate it with flash light you will not get any light back. it exists?
or is it possible to make one such material?

Comment: Do you mean for all wavelengths or just in the regime of visible light?

Comment: Well have a look at the **ferry's black body**

Comment: Only in the regime of visible light I would say

Comment: Worth seeing [Vantablack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantablack)

Comment: Quoted from Wikipedia: " Vantablack is a substance made of carbon nanotubes and is the blackest substance known, absorbing a maximum of 99.965% of radiation in the visible spectrum. It is composed of a forest of vertical tubes which are "grown". When light strikes vantablack, instead of bouncing off, it becomes trapped and is continually deflected between the tubes before eventually becoming heat"

Comment: The closest you can probably get would be a black hole, but that's kind of hard to come by... The engineering solution to your problem is multiple reflections. Even with a material that absorbs just 90% of the radiation, five consecutive reflections will already get the remaining intensity down to 1e-5. This is usually achieved with optical baffle geometries.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121536/is-it-possible-to-have-a-perfectly-black-material

Comment: Did you check [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body#Near-black_materials)?

Comment: if your goal is to eliminate the reflections, you can also play with the flash light. Each lamp has a specific spectrum ( interior photos may accomodate with such adaptations ) , maybe more efficient with a specific matte paint easy to find ...

Comment: @CuriousOne how do you get the number 1e-5? Shouldn't 5 reflections be 0.9^5=0.6 instead of 1e-5?

Comment: @no_choice99  You are multiplying absorbtance, not reflectance.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft my bad, you're absolutely right.