# Which features effect on the Reflection of things?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics

I'm working on something and I need to find a wire that doesn't reflect well.
so, I know one feature is the color of the wire to decrease the reflection. But what other features effect on the reflection of wires? for example, does the type of wire effect or ...

notice that I want a **smooth** wire which doesn't reflect well.

Answer (score 0):

The "blacker" things are the less they reflect. That doesn't necessarily mean they are less visible - just less reflective.

Matt coatings are probably your best bet. There is "the blackest surface there is" - nanotubes that trap the incident light and don't let it out again. Essentially they make the photons interact with the surface multiple times - if you have a high probability of absorption at each interaction, they will eventually all be absorbed.

I wrote a post about this material earlier - see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/183476/26969)

Comment: Thanks, sir. But what other features effect on the reflection?

Comment: What features except the color?

Comment: The other important feature is surface texture. When you have a "shiny" surface you maintain spatial coherence of the light (specular reflection). If you roughen the surface, the total amount of light reflected might be the same - but it doesn't all come from the same place. This makes the reflection less noticeable.

Comment: Incidentally - putting a copper wire just above a smoky candle can put a nice layer of soot on it - this could help make it less reflective (somehow I think this is related to your earlier question about measuring a thin copper wire...)

Comment: Yes, sir. But I want a " smooth " wire which doesn't reflect well. Putting it above smoke decrease the amount of reflection or just make it less unnoticeable?

Comment: Matt black is the best you can hope to do - and the soot will help you get there if you can't fabricate a nano surface. Black by definition is "mostly absorbed", and matt is "what is left is non specular".