# How much black is in black smoke?

Tags: optics

A cloud of black smoke, like from an oil fire, contains transparent gases, and black particles.

How much of a volume of smoke needs to be solid black to make smoke appear black?

- It depends on the size and shape of the particles: If I take all black particles out of a liter of black smoke, and press them to a sphere, I have clear air with a small sphere - but how small?
- it also depends on the orientation: If I shape the particles into a sheet, it can cover much more area than a sphere. So let's assume roughly spherical particles.

Commercial carbon black has various particle shapes and sizes, but we can simplify it to 100 nm and spherical.

Comment: Does this help? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/121536/226902,  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116877/226902 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/183473/226902

Comment: Particles just have to absorb or scatter light in order to effectively block light to an observer.  They do not have to appear black themselves when illuminated.   That said I think you're probably looking for something like the [mass attenuation coeeficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_attenuation_coefficient).